# meteor templates object with array

Tags: templates, meteor

I'm new in meteor templates and trying to render emails from the next user objects with emails array:

```
{
  "_id" : "8ngggLthJ6NRKJRfG",
  "emails" : [
    {
        "address" : "nazar@mail.com",
        "verified" : false
    }
  ]
}
```

Template helper:

```
Template.user.helpers({
  users() {
    return Meteor.users.find({}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 } }).fetch();
  },
});
```

Template:

```
<template name="chats">
  <ul>
   {{#each users}}
     {{> user}}
   {{/each}}
 </ul>
</template>


<template name="user">
  <li>{{emails[0].address}}</li>
</template>
```

but I get error: "Error: Can't call non-function: [object Object]"

How can I fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the correct syntax is `emails.[0].address` with an extra dot, can you try that?

Comment: Yes, it help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`emails` is an array, so kindly use `emails.[0].address`